# TSVECTOR data type substitute

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I have a column in a table in POSTGRES that is TSVECTOR data type, Due to constraints with a tool we are using for data loading within that table, the Column with the TSVECTOR data type isn't being loaded properly.

Are there any other substitute data types that will accomplish similar search functionalities?

Comment: Why wouldn't your unknown broken tool just be broken with anything else we recommend, too?

Comment: Use a better tool.